# How to reference UserLocalService Entity in Service Builder?

Tags: liferay, liferay-service-builder

i am trying to write a Service using Service Builder in Liferay, and here i want extend the UserLocalService.

for example :

```
<entity name="MyJournal" local-service="true" remote-service="true">
        <reference package-path="com.liferay.portlet.journal"
            entity="JournalArticle" />
</entity>
```

So here what we are doing is, we are trying to extend the JournalArticle service. this is working fine.

But what could be the reference entity class for UserLocalService.

Help Highly Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the naming conventions of Liferay, a service is named as `entityService (entityLocalService,entityLocalServiceUtil etc.)` since the name of the class you want to extend is `UserLocalService` the entity would be `com.liferay.portal.model.User`

Comment: thanks for the reply. your answer is partially correct. The thing is we need to extend the model class only. and in this case the class is "User" and the location is "com.liferay.portal".

Answer (score -1):

I done some more research and got the solution.

Here we need to use "`User`" model class and the class path is "`com.liferay.portal`"

So here it would be:

```
<entity name="XXXentity" local-service="true" remote-service="true">
        <reference package-path="com.liferay.portal" entity="User" />
</entity>
```

Here is my some study and some conclusion:
we always need to extend **"Model"** class only.

Comment: Please consider this as a general conclusion and not the answer.